liferay feature to redirect request to file hosted on another server
I am new to Liferay and evaluating Liferay features for below usecase
Problem statement : I have files stored on a webserver which cannot be accessible externally to public.
I have a Liferay webserver where the published assets have external DNS setup and accessible externally, but do not intend to upload all those files to Liferay webcontent
Question:
Does Liferay provide any features to perform the link manipulation (redirect /configure a virtual host)
My need is to generate an external public URL that resolves into the file hosted on the non-public webserver

Not a programming question (see [help/on-topic] and [ask]). Consider bringing it to the Liferay Community (e.g. https://liferay.dev). However: If you talk about redirection, your original files still need to be publicly available on the internet as they'll be requested by the browser right after the redirection. Otherwise you'd need to write a component where Liferay downloads the file from its protected location and forwards the content (not redirects the URL) to the user.
